# Group/Aggregate on different values of a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate

DB is SQL Server 2008

Table A:

Values in 'Identifier' Column: A, B, C, D, E, F
Values in 'Balances' Column: 10, 100, 30, 50, 70, 55

Desired Result Set:

Values in 'Identifier_New' Column: Z, Y, X
Values in sum(Balances) Column: 40, 170, 105

Logical map to sum balances:

sum and group balances of Identifiers A and C as Z.
sum and group balances of Identifiers B and E as Y.
sum and group balances of Identifiers D and E as X.

Can I get the above desired result set in a single sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT x.v AS Identifier_New, SUM(Balances)
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE Identifier
                      WHEN 'A' THEN 'Z'
                      WHEN 'C' THEN 'Z'
                      WHEN 'B' THEN 'Y'
                      WHEN 'E' THEN 'Y'
                      WHEN 'D' THEN 'X'
                      WHEN 'F' THEN 'X'
                    END ) AS x(v)
GROUP BY x.v
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5e3d6/1)

Comment: nice answer.  Is there a performance difference between this and mine or does cross apply serve essentially as shorthand?

Comment: @StanShaw I think `CROSS APPLY` in this case is just syntactic sugar. Both queries should have the same performance.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I am going to read up on it and start using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Identifier = 'A' or Identifier = 'C' THEN 'Z'
    WHEN Identifier = 'B' or Identifier = 'E' THEN 'Y'
    WHEN Identifier = 'D' or Identifier = 'F' THEN 'X' 
    END AS [Identifier_New],
    SUM(Balances) AS [Sum of Balances]
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Identifier = 'A' or Identifier = 'C' THEN 'Z'
    WHEN Identifier = 'B' or Identifier = 'E' THEN 'Y'
    WHEN Identifier = 'D' or Identifier = 'F' THEN 'X' 
    END
```

Comment: I tried both answers from Stan and Giorgos and both worked well. Thanks guys.